# Find span value with xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I'm following [this](http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/)
tutorial for scraping information from a website after a login.
Now, part of the code makes use of a xpath variable to scrape specific content. I'm not familiair with xpath and after a lot of searching I can't find the right solution. I hope one of you guys can help me out!

I need the value within the `"price"` `<span>`:

```
<div class="price-box">
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-64">
<span class="price">€&nbsp;4,90</span>
</span>
</div>
```

My piece of code right now is:

```
# Scrape url
result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
bucket_names = tree.xpath("//span[@class='price']/text()")
```

What should be the xpath code to get the information from within the `<span>`?

Edit: It seems indeed -as per the comments- that the initial page source came not good through.

Comment: You're doing it right already.

Comment: Check whether required data present in initial page source. If not, you might not be able to get it with the same HTTP-request as you do in browser. You can try [request-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) which supports JavaScript execution

Answer (score 0):

your xpath looks almost fine, maybe you forgot a dot?

```
bucket_names = tree.xpath(".//span[@class='price']/text()")
```

Comment: `.` is not needed. `//` searches for any matching node in the tree.

Comment: @marcuse make sure span is there.  `'class="price"' in result.content`

Answer (score 0):

Please check xpath submethod,
Your xpath seems correct.

Try with: `xpath("//span[@class='price']").text`

Comment: `xpath()` returns *list of nodes*. List has no such property as `text`